# Ocaml stringmap calculator AST parse not adding or finding

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

Very close to getting this to work but having trouble with StringMap from OCaml. Essentially I'm making a calculator which takes in from ocamllex the lexical stream ... so here commas are supposed to separate out our expressions while equal signs means that we will be assigning a value to a variable.

I realized that when assigning variables I'm not able to look them up because I get (Fatal error: exception Not_found) on the lines for not finding the key's I added in the Var case of the function. I don't know where to put the StringMap.empty or how to make it visible in this function... I was wondering why it can't find what I'm adding in the equals case?

Here's my code.

```
open Ast

module StringMap = Map.Make(String)

let varMap = StringMap.empty

let rec parser = function

  Lit(x) -> x
| Binop(e1, op, e2) -> (
      let v1 = parser e1 and v2 = parser e2 in
      match op with
            Add -> v1 + v2
            | Sub -> v1 - v2
            | Mul -> v1 * v2
            | Div -> v1 / v2
      )
| Var(v) -> StringMap.find v varMap
| Statements(e1, e2) ->   ignore(parser e1); parser e2
| Equals(v, e1) ->  StringMap.add v e1 varMap; parser e1

let _ =
  let LexingBuffer = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
  let expression = Parser.expression Scanner.token LexingBuffer in
  let result = parser expression in
  print_endline (string_of_int result)
```

Comment: Do you not get a warning form the compiler on `StringMap.add v e1 varMap;` saying you're just throwing the value away?

Comment: @glennsl I did get "Warning 10: this expression should have type unit." on the line you're talking about but I thought that was b/c I'm not returning an int like the other cases and was ok... am I really using add wrong? In that line I'm only doing the add to map first and then returning the expression value after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` is an immutable data structure. Any function that changes the map will return a new modified instance, while leaving the previous one unaltered. Therefore, this expression

```
StringMap.add v e1 varMap; parser e1
```

will just throw the new map away, and return whatever the recursive call to `parser` returns instead. If you want to use `Map` you have to keep the new instance around. You can do so either by making `varMap` a ref cell that you update:

```ml
let varMap = ref StringMap.empty

...

varMap := StringMap.add v1 !varMap
```

or by adding a function argument to `parser` and pass it along:

```ml
let rec parser varMap = function

...

parser (StringMap.add v e1 varMap) e1
```

Another option is to use a [Hashtbl](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html) instead, which *is* mutable and works very well with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are immutable. The line

```
StringMap.add v e1 varMap; parser e1
```

is thus computing an updated map and then *discard* it immediately.
In other words, the map `varMap` is always empty.

To avoid discarding the environment map, you should track it in the function `parser` itself by adding it as an argument of the function — which you might rename to `eval`:

```
  let rec eval env = function
  | ...
```

Comment: Is there a better / another way without changing the function prototype (what it's taking in... I tried moving the  "let varMap = StringMap.empty" into the rec function but it didn't like that ... I see between you and @glennsl that I guess the map is getting discarded after I add value... I need to know how to make this map data struct in this function and I'm set I guess

Comment: Hashmap can be used indeed, and it would be simpler since you don't have local definitions(scopes) in your language. Nevertheless, using an immutable environment might be a good exercice.